# Pandas dataframe change value according to condition from another filed

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe *res* with 4 columns:
Account, Currency, Balance LCY, Balance FCY

i also have a dictionary *rates* that holds all different currency rates (key currency name: value rate as string)
i need to change Balance LCY on accounts that the currency is not EUR to be *Balance FCY / rate*.

i've tried to run:

```
res['Balance LCY'].loc[res['Currency'] != 'EUR'] = res['Balance FCY'] / float(rates[res['Currency']])
```

however im getting an error :

```
TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

any help appreciated.

> It seems that the issue is pulling the value of the specific cell in
>   currency column, to perform the lookup in the external dictionary.
>
> I managed to solve this myself, by turning the dictionary into a dataframe, joining it with the original res dataframe and then performing the calculation.

solution code:

```
erates = pd.DataFrame(list(rates.items()), columns=['Currency', 'Rate'])
res = pd.merge(res, erates, how='left', on='Currency')
res.loc[res['Currency'] != 'EUR', 'Balance LCY'] = res['Balance FCY'] / res['Rate']
```

Sample Data
res:

```
Account,Currency,Balance LCY,Balance FCY
123,EUR,-299183.94,0
124,EUR,-28578532,0
125,EUR,0,0
126,CAD,0,0
127,PLN,0,-2646970
128,ZAR,0,-5026915
129,DKK,0,-2862948.8
130,CHF,0,-343557.9
131,USD,0,-71672.87
132,CAD,0,84295.63
133,SGD,0,-269976.9
134,TRY,0,-494451.56
135,NZD,0,-256601.95
136,JPY,0,0
```

rates:

```
rates= {
"CAD": 1.432,
"HKD": 8.4117,
"ISK": 138.3,
"PHP": 54.955,
"DKK": 7.4702,
"HUF": 337.1,
"CZK": 25.061,
"AUD": 1.6363,
"RON": 4.804,
"SEK": 10.569,
"IDR": 14867.58,
"INR": 77.754,
"BRL": 4.755,
"RUB": 69.548,
"HRK": 7.449,
"JPY": 120.96,
"THB": 34.164,
"CHF": 1.061,
"SGD": 1.5131,
"PLN": 4.2835,
"BGN": 1.9558,
"TRY": 6.6131,
"CNY": 7.5945,
"NOK": 10.0873,
"NZD": 1.7104,
"ZAR": 16.2965,
"USD": 1.0801,
"MXN": 20.5183,
"ILS": 3.6985,
"GBP": 0.8351,
"KRW": 1309.45,
"MYR": 4.5294
}
```

Comment: Please provide sample input and output data to make a [mcve] so that we can better understand your issue

Comment: I suspect the problem is `end_rates[res['Currency']]`. Assuming `end_rates` is a dictionary, this should probably be something like `res['Currency'].map(end_rates)`.

Comment: Added data examples

Comment: Please share the **entire** error message as well as a proper [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's simple design solution to that - you should always add your base currency to your dictionary with FX rate equal 1.

In your case:

```py
rates["EUR"]=1

erates = pd.DataFrame(list(rates.items()), columns=['Currency', 'Rate'])
res = pd.merge(res, erates, how='left', on='Currency')
res["Balance LCY"]=res["Balance FCY"].div(res["Rate"])
```

Outputs:

```py
   Account Currency    Balance LCY  Balance FCY      Rate
0      123      EUR       0.000000         0.00    1.0000
1      124      EUR       0.000000         0.00    1.0000
2      125      EUR       0.000000         0.00    1.0000
3      126      CAD       0.000000         0.00    1.4320
4      127      PLN -617945.605229  -2646970.00    4.2835
5      128      ZAR -308465.928267  -5026915.00   16.2965
6      129      DKK -383249.283821  -2862948.80    7.4702
7      130      CHF -323805.749293   -343557.90    1.0610
8      131      USD  -66357.624294    -71672.87    1.0801
9      132      CAD   58865.663408     84295.63    1.4320
10     133      SGD -178426.343269   -269976.90    1.5131
11     134      TRY  -74768.498889   -494451.56    6.6131
12     135      NZD -150024.526427   -256601.95    1.7104
13     136      JPY       0.000000         0.00  120.9600
```